# jQuery - Setting background-position to where the mouse moves

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am attempting to make a custom zoom feature for a WordPress site. The zoom feature works however I am unable to make it follow my mouse - to zoom in towards the cursor.

The method I have used is quite long winded so will start with hopefully a simple question.

**CSS**

Wrote a little snip that will fill its parent and allow me to apply the zoom styles - applied in the jQuery on mouseover / out.

A thing to note which I am trying to think of a work around for is the background-size: cover. This prevents the image from slipping out of position - but I feel can't be used if I want to adjust the position?

Anyway here is the CSS:

```
.photo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    transition: transform .5s ease-out;
}
```

**jQuery**

I have targeted my anchor that contains the image I wish to zoom.

Appended a container to contain the zooming image.

Set the background-image using the src.

Applied the scale on mouse over / out.

Now on mouse move I have tried setting the transform origin and the background position like this:

```
//transform-origin
.on('mousemove', function(e){
    $(this).children('.photo').css({'transform-origin': ((e.pageX - $(this).offset().left) / $(this).width()) * 100 + '% ' + ((e.pageY - $(this).offset().top) / $(this).height()) * 100 +'%'});
            console.log('transform-origin should adjust');
})
//background-position
.on('mousemove', function(e){
    $(this).children('.photo').css({'background-position': ((e.pageX - $(this).offset().left) / $(this).width()) * 100 + '% ' + ((e.pageY - $(this).offset().top) / $(this).height()) * 100 +'%'});
    console.log('background-position should adjust');
})
```

This has no effect and can't figure out why - it is the same $(this).children('.photo') as the other functions (console logs work) and the math when I work through it is logical and should yield the correct figures.

I guess my question is why this doesn't zoom to the correct area of the image? Is there a work around for the background-size: cover?

I will build a jsfiddle or something now...

Comment: can you use  $(this).find('.photo')... instead of .children(...

Comment: What selector is `.on('mousemove', function(e){` applied to? It should be something like `$('#selectorOfElement').on(...`

Comment: Thank you, both valid in my eyes however it turns out the code was working I just had to apply some further CSS to the anchor that contained the images.

Answer (score 0):

When creating a JSFiddle I have figured out it was due to the anchor the image sits within didn't have these settings applied:

```
display: block;

position: relative;

overflow: hidden;
```

If you're looking to see it in action here it is:

https://jsfiddle.net/48od0axj/

Here is the original I used to give me the idea and manipulated to work for my purpose:

https://codepen.io/ccrch/pen/yyaraz